# Не могу считать данные из файла, ошибка кастинга

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Учу java и пишу только на java core. Пробую написать маленький проект следуя трeхуровневой архитектуре. Что я пробую сделать.

1. У меня есть класс User данные этого класса я успешно записал в файлик.
2. Дальше эти данные я хочу прочитать с файлика и уже с помощью других методов с этими данными работать.

ПРОБЛЕМА в том что при чтение с файла мне выпадает ошибка.

Как это исправить чтобы я мог использовать эти данные для других методов (которые в будущем буду писать)?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class Model.User (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Model.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Repository.UserRepository.readObject(UserRepository.java:35)
    at Demo.UserDemo.main(UserDemo.java:21)
```

Пробовал решать проблему через другой метод записи и чтения с файла и в какой-то момент снова выпадала эта ошибка. Очень прощу вашей помощи.

Class User

```
package Model;

import java.util.Objects;

public class User extends GeneralModelClass {

    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private UserType userType;

    public User(Long id, String userName, String password, String country, UserType userType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id) &&
                Objects.equals(userName, user.userName) &&
                Objects.equals(password, user.password) &&
                Objects.equals(country, user.country) &&
                userType == user.userType;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, userName, password, country, userType);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", userType=" + userType +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Класс UserDemo  где я запускаю код

```
package Demo;

import Controller.UserController;
import DataBase.Path;
import Model.User;
import Model.UserType;
import Repository.UserRepository;

public class UserDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UserController userController = new UserController();
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
        Path path = new Path();
        User user1 = new User(1L, "nameTest1", "01234", "PL", UserType.USER);
        User user2 = new User(2L, "nameTest2", "56789", "PL", UserType.USER);

        //userController.registerUser(user2, path.userDB);//работает
        userRepository.readObject(path.userDB);// не работает
    }
}
```

Класс Repository

```
import Model.User;

import java.util.Random;

public class UserRepository extends GeneralRepository<User> {
    
    public User registerUser(User user, String path) throws Exception {
        return writeObject(user, path);
    }

    @Override
    public String typeRecord(User user) {
        Random random = new Random();
        user.setId(random.nextLong());
        if (user.getId() < 0) {
            user.setId(-1 * user.getId());
        }
        return user.getId() + "," + user.getCountry() + "," + user.getPassword() + "," + user.getUserName() + "," + user.getUserType();
    }

    @Override
    public User readObject(String path) throws Exception {
        return super.readObject(path);
    }
}
```

И класс с методами на чтение и запись

```
package Repository;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class GeneralRepository<T> {
    Validation validation = new Validation();

    public T readObject(String path) throws Exception {
        validation.validate(path);
        List<T> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                objectList.add((T) line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File with path " + path + " not found");
        }
        System.out.println(objectList.toString());
        return (T) objectList.toString();
    }
    
    public T writeObject(T t, String path) throws Exception {
        validation.validate(path);
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true))) {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.length() != 0)
                bw.append("\n");
            bw.append(typeRecord(t));
            return t;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Can't write to file" + path);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public abstract String typeRecord(T t);
}
```

Comment: `objectList.add((T) line);` почему вы решили, что можете просто так взять строку и привести её к любому типу? Возьмите арбуз, назовите его бананом, но он не станет от этого бананом.

Comment: `return (T) objectList.toString();` а это вообще что должно было сделать?

Answer (score 1):

@tym32167 прав в том смысле что вам нужно будет написать interface какой-нибудь parsable и реализовывать его в ваших классах для вызова их в местах где описал @tym32167.

```
 objectList.add(T.parse(line)); //для парсинга

 public List<T implements Parsable> readObject(String path) // объявление метода. возращяем лист так как предполагаем несколько объектов.
```

Ну и возврат тогда будет адекватным

```
 return objectList;
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял,( так на будущее) чтобы я мог юзать данные с файлика, мне надо их парсить к примеру в Long и потом уже их использовать в других методах?

Comment: Да, именно. Где то это парсинн а местами сериализация